# Validate end date should be greater than start date?

Tags: asp.net

```html
datePicker.ascx
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDatePicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:ImageButton runat="Server" ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.png" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" /> 
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender Format="dd/MM/yyyy" ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txtDatePicker" runat="server" PopupButtonID="Image1" />

register.aspx
<%@ Register Src="~/Modules/datePicker.ascx" TagName ="datePicker" TagPrefix ="uc1"  %>

Start Date   <uc1:datePicker ID="datePickerSD" runat="server" >
End Date     <uc1:datePicker ID="datePickerED" runat="server" />
 <asp:CustomValidator  ID="CustomValidator1"  ControlToValidate="datePickerED"
                      ErrorMessage="End date should be greater than start date" runat="server" />
```

Tried to get clientid of start date..but confused..

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpr" runat="server" ControlToCompare ="txtDate1" ControlToValidate="txtDate2" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Date" ErrorMessage="To date should great than small data"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Have you tried compare validator ? This can help you

Comment: Please look at the above code, I used ajax calendarextender.. How to get clientid of datePickerSD in the ControlToCompare property?

Comment: Then you have to compare it using jquery or JavaScript

Comment: I try to use javascript and jquery. but I could pass value of datapicker. please see above code and I added customvalidator  and  called javascript <asp:CustomValidator  ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="<%# Eval(datePickerED.ClientID) %>" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateDate" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="End date should be greater than start date" EnableClientScript="true" />

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

```html
<asp:CompareValidator ID="compareValidatorDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="datePickerED$txtDatePicker" ControlToCompare ="datePickerSD$txtDatePicker" CultureInvariantValues="true" 
                                            ErrorMessage="End date should be greater than start date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" SetFocusOnError="false" Type="String" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CompareValidator>
```